# Can't extract latest civicrm-4.7.22-drupal.tar.gz to install

Tags: drupal, upgrade, error

Trying to upgrade civicrm for drupal to 4.7.22 on a linux machine.  I've tried downloading the file from both the civicrm.org site and sourcefourge.  Get the following error when extracting:

tar -xzf civicrm-4.7.22-drupal.tar.gz

> tar: civicrm/vendor/pear/net_smtp/README.rst: Cannot create symlink to
>   `docs/guide.txt': No such file or directory tar: Exiting with failure
>   status due to previous errors

I then extracted using 7-zip on a windows 10 machine, hoping to ftp the folder up directly, but not all the folders are there.

The sourceforge extracted civicrm folder is different from the one I downloaded from the civicrm site (using beyond compare).  I'm not confident installing either one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested those two downloads, and found:

- The two tar.gz files are identical (MD5=`26e2db3c52d105659acc293cc2ffc74c` for civicrm-4.7.22-drupal.tar.gz)
- Yes, there's an invalid symlink in the file.

That "bad" symlink might offend some tools (and might trigger anti-virus warnings) but it's harmless and should not affect the CiviCRM files you've downloaded. It links a README in one of our packages from that package's docs dir to the package root, and we strip that docs folder out of the code we ship.

I have opened an issue ([CRM-20884](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20884)) & submitted a small fix ([PR10676](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10676)) to resolve that missing symlink in some upcoming release.

Thanks for raising this! You did the right thing to question what you were seeing. FWIW, I recommend downloading from https://civicrm.org/download in favour of SourceForge.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it extracted everything but the offending symlink.  I went ahead and installed as is.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This file also causes an error in Drupal Backup and Migrate.   Deleting the link solved the problem but it will likely recur if future upgrades include the link, I presume